# Apply jquery ui theme to page

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, themes

Tried following code to apply theme to select box.  FF says `$("select#menu").selectmenu is not a function`. Btw I declared jquery, jquery-ui before this script

```
$('select#menu').selectmenu({
    style:'dropdown'
});
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The selectmenu functionality is not a standard feature but a plugin. Have you loaded the plugin as well?

The other option is that there's no element `select#menu`. The `select` part is redundant anyway; you could just use `#menu`.

Also make sure the code is inside `$( function() { .. })`:

```
$( function() {
    $('#menu').selectmenu({
        style:'dropdown'
    });
});
```

Comment: code is inside `$(document).ready(function () {` and i loaded whole jquery-ui library before. Take a look at this pages source http://view.jqueryui.com/selectmenu/demos/selectmenu/default.html They used `select#menu`

Comment: That page says: "The Selectmenu **widgets** *(sic)* provides..." It's a widget, i.e. it's not included in the basic library. See http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12138056/Selectmenu

Comment: now i'm getting something like that http://prntscr.com/3ilqv the left menu is jquery ui autocomplete combobox applied menu, to the left one (which doesn't work properly) i applied `$('#menu').selectmenu();`